# How to download csv file from server using stream

Tags: javascript, stream, aurelia

I'm trying to download huge CSV file from server which is being generated on the fly. 
Im returning `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>` in async so as soon as i have part of my data i'm returning it.
this is my controller code:

```
StreamingResponseBody streamingResponseBody = out -> {
     csvService.exportToCsvBySessionId(applicationId, sessionIdsInRange, out, tags);
}
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(csvService.getHeaders(CSV_FILE_NAME))
    .body(streamingResponseBody);
```

in the header i'm adding

`produces: text\csv;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s.csv;`

On the client side im using aurelia framework and sending the request using HttpClient (fetch)

```
public getFraudAlertsCsv() {
            this.serverProxy.fetch(`/sessions/fraud/csv)
                .then(response => { 
                    logger.debug('waiting for response');
                    return response.blob());
                .then((blob: Blob) => this.donwnloadCsv(blob, `Fraud_Alerts_${new Date()}.csv`))
                .catch( (err)=> {
                    this.logger.error("Failed to get appSessionId sessions csv file", err);
                });
        }
```

even though i can see in the network analysis that my request is starting to get response (it size increases) there is no popup window asking to download the file, and the log doesn't print "waiting for response".
instead im getting the whole file being download what the entire response arrived (when server close the stream).

I want to show the progress of the download, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think `fetch` doesn't support progress API yet, so you may want to use traditional XHR and use onprogress or progress event:

```javascript
xhr.onprogress = function updateProgress(oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total * 100;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}
```

Note: code example taken from MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress